# Function satisfying $F(a)-F(1)=F(1)-F(\frac{1}{a})$

Tags: statistics, functions, probability-distributions, statistical-inference, monotone-functions

What continuous monotone increasing function has the property:

$$F(a)-F(1)=F(1)-F(\frac{1}{a}) \space\space\space\space\space\space \forall a>1 $$

The context for this is that I'm looking for a continuous probability distribution on $(0,\infty)$ satisfying:

$$P\left(1\le x\le a\right) = P\left(\frac{1}{a} \le x \le 1\right)$$

Comment: This is a huge class of functions.  Even in the restricted context of $F$ being the CDF of a random variable supported on $(0,\infty)$, you're just looking for any continuous, monotone increasing function $F$ such that $F(1) = 1/2$ and $\lim_{t\to\infty}F(t) = 1$ (the property then defines $F$ on $(0,1)$)

Comment: If you can transform $x$ in a certain way, any odd function $f(x)$ that has a finite limit when $x\to\infty$ could be used. I will add the detail in an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any odd and monotonic increasing function $g(x)$ that has a limit of $\frac12$ when $x\to+\infty$ could work. You define $f(x)=g(\log(x))+\frac12$.

You have the following properties:
$$f(1)=\frac12$$
$$f(1/x) + f(x) = 1$$
$$\lim_{x\to0}f(x)=0$$
$$\lim_{x\to+\infty}f(x)=1$$

Answer (score 1):

$$F(a)=\log(a)+C$$
Satisfies for any real $C$.

Using the fundamental theorem of calculus, your equation becomes (I'm assuming a differentiable solution)
$$\int_1^a F'(x)dx=\int_{1/a}^1 F'(x)dx$$
Moving everything to the left and differentiating leads to
$$F'(a)-F'(1/a)1/a^2=0$$
We are then left with the functional equation
$$aF'(a)=F'(1/a)\frac{1}{a}$$
Assume $F'(a)=a^n$ for some $n$. By plugin this into the previous equation we have $n=-1$. So
$$F'(a)=1/a$$
Is a candidate. Integration leads to
$$F(a)=\log(a)+C.$$
Showing that this is an actual solution is simple.